# How to click on the 'Show More' button on a lazy loading webpage

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, lazy-loading, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click 'Show More' button on a web page.
I wrote this code but get an error below the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

#Open Chrome
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/chromedriver.exe")

web="https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?adults=1&destination=Montreal%2C%20Quebec%2C%20Canada&endDate=2019-09-16&latLong=45.50195%2C-73.56714&localDateFormat=M%2Fd%2Fyyyy&regionId=178288&sort=recommended&startDate=2019-09-15&useRewards=true"
driver.get(web)
driver.maximize_window()

#parse html        
html =driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

#click show more
show_more=driver.find_element_by_link_text('Show More')
#Another element is covering the element you are to click.    
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", show_more)
```

Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Show More"}
```

At first, I didn't include the last line (execute_script...) but thought it would work if I include that line but still the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

An extra question is that is there any way to click 'Show More' button multiple times? because I noticed that I had to click multiple times to look up all the hotel listings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use the below css.

```
button[data-stid='show-more-results']
```

**Script:**

```
# scroll to the element before clicking
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-stid='show-more-results']").location_once_scrolled_into_view
# click on the show more button
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-stid='show-more-results']").click()
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Since you are using the same locator more than once, you should store it in a variable and then use the variable in the two finds. That way if the locator changes, you only have to change it in one spot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the button with text as **Show More** multiple times after scrolling it within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and to achieve that you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?adults=1&destination=Montreal%2C%20Quebec%2C%20Canada&endDate=2019-09-16&latLong=45.50195%2C-73.56714&localDateFormat=M%2Fd%2Fyyyy&regionId=178288&sort=recommended&startDate=2019-09-15&useRewards=true")
  while True:
      try:
          driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Show More']"))))
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Show More']"))))
          print("Show More button clicked")
      except:
          print("No more Show More button")
          break
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Show More button clicked
  Show More button clicked
  Show More button clicked
  .
  No more Show More button
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Show More')]")).click()